# Make a POST request in php using curl

Tags: php, http, post, curl, httprequest

I have the following command that works perfectly on the command line,

```
curl -X POST --header 'Category: network;scheme="http://schemas.ogf.org/occi/infrastructure#";class="kind";,virtualnetwork; scheme="http://schemas.opennebula.org/occi/infrastructure#";class="mixin";' --header 'X-OCCI-Attribute: occi.core.title="My Network",occi.core.summary="A short summary", opennebula.network.size=256, opennebula.network.address="192.168.0.0",opennebula.network.bridge=virbr0,opennebula.network.public=YES,opennebula.network.type=RANGED' http://localhost:4567/network/
```

I've tried to make the same request using cURL extension in php as follows:

```
    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost:4567/network/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Category : network;scheme="http://schemas.ogf.org/occi/infrastructure#",class="kind"',
        'Category : virtualnetwork; scheme="http://schemas.opennebula.org/occi/infrastructure#";class="mixin"'));

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-OCCI-Attribut : occi.core.title="Third Network"',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : occi.core.summary="Test Net"', 
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.size=256',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.address="10.10.10.0"',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.bridge=br0',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.public=YES',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.type=RANGED'
        ) );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The request fails and nothing is added on the server.

I've tried also the HTTPRequest but still unable to  make the request:

```
            $arg= array(
        'Category : network;scheme="http://schemas.ogf.org/occi/infrastructure#",class="kind"',
        'Category : virtualnetwork; scheme="http://schemas.opennebula.org/occi/infrastructure#";class="mixin"',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : occi.core.title="Third Network"',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : occi.core.summary="Test Net"', 
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.size=256',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.address="10.10.10.0"',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.bridge=br0',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.public=YES',
        'X-OCCI-Attribut : opennebula.network.type=RANGED'
        ) ;

        $this->httpRequest->addPostFields($arg);
```

### Any suggestions ??

I've added the following line according to [this link](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/php-and-curl-disabling-100-continue-header/):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

and got :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 29 Jul 2011 09:01:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Server: OCCI/1.1
```

---

I've succeded, I needed just to correct the headers, 
and remove the

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

The correct header is :

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Category: network;scheme="http://schemas.ogf.org/occi/infrastructure#";class="kind";,virtualnetwork; scheme="http://schemas.opennebula.org/occi/infrastructure#";class="mixin";',
        'X-OCCI-Attribute: occi.core.title="My Net",occi.core.summary="A netw summary", opennebula.network.size=256, opennebula.network.address="10.0.0.0",opennebula.network.bridge=virbr0,opennebula.network.public=YES,opennebula.network.type=RANGED')); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to debug network flow.

Comment: GET and DELETE request are successful, so I suspect the request is wrong, no problem with the network

Comment: you can also look at the content which is being transfered. Do you notice a difference between `curl` command and curl extension?

Comment: That's a key, if you could help me figure out a way to "translate" curl commands to curl extension instructions

Comment: I don't know libCurl..I just wanted to give you an idea and a tool to approach your problem :) I suggest you download wireshark and look at the TCP content from `curl` then compare your TCP content from your curl extension. Then you see what's going on. Or you wait for someone who posts the correct answer :)

Comment: I'm using live http headers extension of firefox to monitor the communication, should be enough, no really need to analyse packets with wireshark, thx